# How do you develop the HTML portion of a Jinja2 template, after you've jinja-ified the file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, templates, jinja2, server-side-rendering

I have an HTML email template that I've created and converted to a jinja template. This mean that I've:

1. Changed it to a `.j2` file extension
2. Added all the necessary jinja expressions like for-loops, if-statements, and expressions, using `{{ ... }}` and `{% ... %}`

The question that I see no obvious answer to is:

#### How do I continue to work on the HTML portion of a Jinja template, after I've already implemented all the Jinja2-specific syntax?

If I were to try and edit it as a regular HTML file, all the curly braces would show up and I don't even know how it would interpret the control-structure elements like for-loops and if-statements.

Let me know if I need to share more context!

Comment: Write a small HTTP server/view which feeds some data into the template and renders it to the browser?

Comment: but then if I try to edit that rendered file or add new html, then I’ll have to re-add all the jinja fields again

Comment: So do you mean you don't like working around the curly braces when editing the HTML part of the file?

Comment: You appear to not have understood me. The problem is that you want to see the _rendered result_, but you want to edit the Jinja template, right? So write a small HTTP server or add a view to your existing server, which _renders the template with some data_. Then edit the template, and look at the rendered result. Rinse, repeat.

Comment: Ok that makes sense! Instead of editing+viewing the original file or editing+viewing the rendered file, I can edit the original file and view the rendered file